# Cannot install package `libxerces27-dev` when installing `phc` php compiler

Tags: 11.10, package-management, php, compiler

To install `phc` following this [guide](http://www.phpcompiler.org/doc/latest/install.html) in Ubuntu Oneiric 11.04, I get error saying that the package is not available as below screenshot.

Searching for the package at ubuntu's package search page result in no luck for me.

Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo aptitude install ~nlibxerces
```

or

```
apt-cache search --names-only xerces
```

Those instructions are out-of-date.  It's not `libxerces27` anymore.